# Write to Google Sheets (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-sheets

I extracted data from a website which is now in a dictionary.
Now, I want to write the data to Google Sheets (an existing one), but I'm having a hard time.

I've used the sample from Google Sheets API but I get a ReferenceError: gapi is not defined.

I have already created a client id for oAuth. Can anyone guide me on simple writing to google sheets from a chrome extension

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "xxx ",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
   "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "xxx"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("GET", "xx--url--xx", false);
    xhr.send()
    var result = xhr.responseText;

    var product = []
    parsedResult = result.split(/\r\n|\n/)

    for (var i = 2; i < parsedResult.length - 1; i++) {
        var data = parsedResult[i].split(';')
        product.push({key: data[1], value: data[2]})
    }
    console.log(product)
    //Product current holds the data in dictionary format


    var gSheets = "-----link to google sheets I want to insert data-----"
    chrome.tabs.create({url: gSheets})


    var values = [
        ["Product Name", "Quantity"]
      ];
      var body = {
        values: values
      };

            gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
              spreadsheetId: "-----spreadsheetID-----",
              range: "Sheet1!1:2",
              valueInputOption: 'RAW',
              resource: body
            }).then((response) => {
              var result = response.result;
              console.log(`${result.updatedCells} cells updated.`);
            });

});
```